# SQL Have three rows of output, need one

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a project where I need to summarize invoices, most of it is pretty easy as I am just reading from the Invoice_master table.  I also need to summarize two fields based on location.  I'm able to get the data but it leaves me with three rows of output for every invoice. How do I get it down to one?

```
select INVCE_31 as "Invoice Number",
    CAST(INVDTE_31 as date) as "Invoice Date",
    CUSTID_31 as "Customer ID",
    ORDNUM_31 as "Sales Order",
    LNETOT_31 - ORDDSC_31 as "Net Amount",
    FRTAMT_31 as "Freight Amount",
    TAXTOT_31 as "Tax Total",
    TAX1_31 as "Invoice Tax",
    LNETOT_31 as "Inovice Total",
    sum(case 
            when ID.STK_32 = 'SAMPLE'
                then PRICE_32
            else 0
            end) as LOCSAMPLE,
    sum(case 
            when ID.STK_32 = 'LITERTRE'
                then PRICE_32
            else 0
            end) as LOCLITERTRE
from Invoice_Master im
left join Invoice_Detail id on im.INVCE_31 = id.INVCE_32
where INVCE_31 = '00084048'
group by ID.STK_32,
    IM.INVCE_31,
    IM.INVDTE_31,
    IM.CUSTID_31,
    IM.ORDNUM_31,
    IM.LNETOT_31,
    IM.TAX1_31,
    IM.ORDDSC_31,
    IM.FRTAMT_31,
    IM.TAXTOT_31
```

Output:

```
 Invoice Number Invoice Date    Customer ID Sales Order Net Amount  Freight Amount  Tax Total   Invoice Tax Inovice Total   LOCSAMPLE   LOCLITERTRE
 00084048       2016-06-30       BAYKIT      20088547   4549.61             20       4569.61    319.87      12708.4          0           793.72
 00084048       2016-06-30       BAYKIT      20088547   4549.61             20       4569.61    319.87      12708.4          0           0
 00084048       2016-06-30       BAYKIT      20088547   4549.61             20       4569.61    319.87      12708.4          213         0
```

Comment: Could you share your current output?

And what is happening when you add distinct keyword like: "select DISTINCT ...."

Comment: @Eray - How will distinct help? there is already GROUP BY present.

Comment: Yep, I see it. but he is saying that he sees exactly same rows 3 times for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `GROUP BY` on `CAST(INVDTE_31 as date)` instead of `INVDTE_31` which would create duplicate if there are multiple record on the same date but different time:

```
select invce_31 as "invoice number",
    cast(invdte_31 as date) as "invoice date",
    custid_31 as "customer id",
    ordnum_31 as "sales order",
    lnetot_31 - orddsc_31 as "net amount",
    frtamt_31 as "freight amount",
    taxtot_31 as "tax total",
    tax1_31 as "invoice tax",
    lnetot_31 as "inovice total",
    sum(case 
            when id.stk_32 = 'sample'
                then price_32
            else 0
            end) as locsample,
    sum(case 
            when id.stk_32 = 'litertre'
                then price_32
            else 0
            end) as loclitertre
from invoice_master im
left join invoice_detail id on im.invce_31 = id.invce_32
where invce_31 = '00084048'
group by im.invce_31,
    cast(invdte_31 as date),
    im.custid_31,
    im.ordnum_31,
    im.lnetot_31,
    im.tax1_31,
    lnetot_31 - orddsc_31,
    im.frtamt_31,
    im.taxtot_31
```

Comment: oh, nice catch!

Comment: Thanks GurV, still no change but every little bit helps.

Comment: @Onyxtacular - Try now please

Answer (score 0):

You are using ID.STK_32 from Invoice_Detail table in grouping clause.
If ID.STK_32 values 'LITERTRE','SAMPLE' and other can appear for one invoice it will cause duplicates.